# How to handle expandable ViewHolders in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` working with `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` in my app. The `ViewHolders` implement an expandable 'quick actions' menu that expands on tapping the item, and the ideal behavior is to have only one item expanded at a time. Expanding one item should collapse all other items in the adapter.

When there are few enough items to fit them all on screen, this works fine. But if the list extends off-screen, when I try to iterate over the adapter's items, I get a `NullPointerException` thrown when the detached or off-screen ViewHolders try to call `getParent()`.

How can I iterate over all ViewHolders in the adapter, or alternatively, only iterate over visible ones?

Relevant adapter code:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BrewViewHolder holder, 
               int position, @NonNull Brew brew) {

    // Bind Views
    holder.bind(brew);

    // Set expander ClickListener
    holder.card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
            if (i != position) {
                // ERROR THROWN HERE
                BrewViewHolder vh = ((BrewViewHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(recyclerView.getChildAt(i)));
                vh.expanded = false;
            }
        }
        holder.expanded = !holder.expanded;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
   });

}
```

Relevant ViewHolder code:

```
public class BrewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    // Expanded state
    public boolean expanded = false;
    ...

    public BrewViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ...
        // Set visibility of quick actions based on expanded state
        quickActions.setVisibility(expanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** As [Gilberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680254/gilberto-ibarra) pointed out, this is very expensive. Went with a version of [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2932967/andrew-churilo)'s solution:

```
private int expandedItemIndex = -1;

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BrewViewHolder holder, int position,
                                @NonNull Brew brew) {
    // Bind Views
    holder.bind(brew);

    // Set expander ClickListener
    holder.card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (position == expandedItemIndex) {
            holder.expanded = false;
            expandedItemIndex = -1;
        } else {
            holder.expanded = true;
            if (expandedItemIndex != -1) {
                BrewViewHolder otherHolder = ((BrewViewHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(
                        recyclerView.getChildAt(expandedItemIndex)));
                otherHolder.expanded = false;
            }
            expandedItemIndex = position;
        }
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, recyclerView.getChildCount());
    });

}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to use `lisawray/Groupie`'s `ExpandableGroup`s.

Comment: Hoping to do this without external libraries. Is there a simplification somewhere of their implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not iterate all views. You need just save index of expanded view and call `notifyDataSetChanged` or `notifyItemChanged`.

```
private int expandedItemIndex = -1;

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BrewViewHolder holder, 
               final int position, @NonNull Brew brew) {

    // Bind Views
    holder.bind(brew);

    // Set expander ClickListener
    holder.card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (position == expandedItemIndex) {
            notifyItemChanged(position);
            expandedItemIndex = -1;
        } else {
            if (expandedItemIndex != -1) {
                notifyItemChanged(expandedItemIndex);
            }
            expandedItemIndex = position;
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
   });

   if (position == expandedItemIndex) {
      // Expand
      holder.quickActions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   } else {
      // Collapse
      holder.quickActions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I think it could cause a NPE if an expanded item is scrolled off screen and another item is clicked? What happens when you `notifyItemChanged(positionOfItemOffScreen)`? Also, you're notifying before the item has actually changed...

Comment: @tobiasfried You don't get NPE with my code. For offscreen items method onBindViewHolder just will not called. `notifyItemYYY` methods update view isn't immediately, so all is right.

Comment: Working like a charm! Well done man.

Answer (score 0):

If(vh!=null){ vh.expanded(false);}

Or

Use try, catch)))

Comment: if (position == expandedItemIndex) {
       // Expand
   } else {
      // Collapse
   }.     I guess it will give the same results

Comment: Yea, still fails. My problem is that `mAdapter.getItemCount()` returns the total number of items, inflated or not.

Comment: Hah, okey, try to get the last visible element from adapter, I did it in onscrolllistener, but i'm not sure, how could you get it in adapter

Comment: Oh, ok, I got it, just check if view is null do nothing

Comment: If(vh!=null){ vh.expanded(false);}

Comment: would have to be `if (recyclerView.getChildAt(i) != null) {vh.expanded = false}`. You can't get the VH if you can't get the child View.

Comment: Try to surround it with try catch, just one line of code

Answer (score 0):

Solved by iterating over `i < recyclerView.getChildCount()` and making sure to cleanup the VH in `onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder)`:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BrewViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Brew brew) {
    // Bind Views
    holder.bind(brew);

    // Set expander ClickListener
    holder.card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (i != position) {
                BrewViewHolder otherHolder = ((BrewViewHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(recyclerView.getChildAt(i)));
                otherHolder.expanded = false;
            }
        }
        holder.expanded = !holder.expanded;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, recyclerView.getChildCount());
    });
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull BrewViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    holder.expanded = false;
}
```